# Why am I getting a NullReferenceException when my variable is instantiated in the "awake" method?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I keep getting this error when I click the Card so I can move it.

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   CardProspector.OnMouseUpAsButton () (at Assets/__Scripts/CardProspector.cs:17)
>   UnityEngine.SendMouseEvents:DoSendMouseEvents(Int32, Int32)

The exception indicates the following method in my `CardProspector` class:

```
override public void OnMouseUpAsButton() {
    Prospector.S.CardClicked(this);  // line 17
    base.OnMouseUpAsButton();
}
```

But that variable should have been instantiated by my `Prospector` class, the relevant portion of which is shown below:

```
public class Prospector : MonoBehaviour {
    static public Prospector S;
    ...
    ...

    // Use this for initialization
    void awake() {
        S = this;
    }

    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: i guess that awake has not been called so S is null

Comment: Side note: Providing small piece of code that demonstrates the problem makes for better SO questions. As with all debugging questions [rubber duck debugging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) is useful technique...

Comment: @GrantWinney looks good to me - reopened. Comment will self-destruct in 10.. 9...

Answer (score 3):

Awake() is case sensitive and will never be called in your code.

Answer (score 0):

This part of the message gives away where the problem is:

```
(at Assets/__Scripts/CardProspector.cs:17)
```

That ":17" means line 17 of your CardProspector.cs file, which translates to the following line:

```
Prospector.S.CardClicked(this);
```

That would suggest that static property "S" is null--it hasn't been defined.

Since "S" is defined in method Awake(), you need to call Awake() before you reference property "S" in any way.